# MVC Editor Template not firing after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, appharbor, mvc-editor-templates

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @ngm comment i have downloaded the build from bitbuket and found that indeed the file is not located in the correct path.

I looked again in the repository in bitbucket and it's there ...
How can that happen ?

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I have created the following editor template:

```
@model CamelotFaultManagement.Models.OptionListViewModel
<div class="btn-group">

@foreach (var item in Model.ListItems)
{
    string RadioButtonID = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName+item.ItemID; 

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedItemID, item.ItemID, new { id = RadioButtonID })
    <label class="btn" for="@RadioButtonID">@item.ItemName</label>
}

</div>
```

and i placed the OptionListViewModel.cshtml in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates

And used it in the following view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FaultTypeID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FaultTypeID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FaultTypeID)  
</div>
```

model.FaultTypeID is of type OptionListViewModel

When i run my app locally everything works just fine but after deployment to appharbor it dose not work, as if it cannot find the editor template at all (see screenshots).
[image: Local]

[image: AppHarbor]

Comment: Basic question, but you're sure OptionListViewModel.cshtml has been deployed to apphb?

Comment: Wow!!!! you are right !!! just downloaded the build.... but it is connected to bi-bucket .. how come its not in the published website ?!

Comment: I can see the file in my repository in bitbucket !!! why app harbor does not pull it ?!

Comment: Okay i found something.. the build action for that specific editor template view was set to none for some reason.. i have change it to "content" and now testing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So...
Many thanks to @ngm for pointing me to the right direction..

The `OptionListViewModel.cshtml` was not included in the release build in app-harbor for some reason.. 
After looking into the porject file chages in git i have notieced that the build action for that specific editor template view was set to "none" for some reason.. I have change it to "content" and now app-harbor copies the file and everything works.

Comment: I had the same problem with a Display Template in a subfolder called ~\Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\. Once I changed the Build Action in the Properties to "Content", it publishes and works fine on the web server now. Until I changed that, it only worked locally running out of Visual Studio in IIS Express. Thanks!